# Bootstrap navbar links don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My friends have asked me to make a website for their production company, which I've been working on, but as I am not a professional web designer, I've run into some issues. I've worked on this site by customizing a template I found online. However, I've come across an issue that I can't seem to fix despite searching here and on several other sites. The links in the navbar do not function when clicked. I was hoping someone could take a look and see if they've got any suggestions. The site can be found [here](http://greatredspotproductions.com).

This is my index HTML file-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow,snippet,archive">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Great Red Spot Productions | New Orleans, LA</title>

    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700,100%7CRoboto:400,700,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Bootstrap and Font Awesome css -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/style.default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom stylesheet - for your changes -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- owl carousel css -->

    <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS Animations -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">

    <!-- Mordernizr -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Responsivity for older IE -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navigation" data-offset="120">

    <!-- *** NAVBAR ***
_________________________________________________________ -->

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#navbar -->

    <!-- *** NAVBAR END *** -->


    <div id="all">


        <!-- *** INTRO IMAGE ***
_________________________________________________________ -->
        <div id="intro" class="clearfix">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <span class="pull-left"><h1 data-animate="fadeInDown">Great Red Spot Productions</h1><span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- *** INTRO IMAGE END *** -->


    <!-- /#all -->

    <!-- #### JAVASCRIPT FILES ### -->

    <!-- js base -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- for demo purpose -->
    <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

    <!-- waypoints for scroll spy -->
    <script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>

    <!-- maps -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/gmaps.js"></script>

    <!-- masonry layout -->
    <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- owl carousel -->
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


    <!-- jQuery scroll to -->
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery counter -->
    <script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery parallax -->
    <script src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>

    <!-- main js file -->

    <script src="js/front.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure what other files would be necessary for help, please just let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you have any code to add to your question?

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I accidentally submitted without inserting the code. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: When I open the page I am receiving Script Errors.. `Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null reference`.  This could be contributing to the problem at hand.  Did you write any of the javascript, or was it already done for you?

Comment: Could you please open your dev tools window and paste the error as well.  When asking a question in SO, it is useful to provide the problem, the code snippet and the error.

Comment: It would be better if you could share a bit more code to make the understanding of users clear on your question. Current code that you have posted is quite vague.

Comment: Along with @XYZ answer.. once you go into the console.. you get a specific [error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error).. seems as though you copy and pasted the code, and without correct Google API authentication, the scripts you are referencing in your code will not work.

Comment: The javascript was already included in the template file. I didn't edit any of it. What other code would be beneficial for me to add here?

Answer (score 3):

There are errors in your javascript.Open the developer tools you can view that.That errors may be preventing that links from functioning.

[image: Check this]

Comment: I saw the same errors, but I have no idea what to do about it, I don't know anything about javascript. I'm just trying to do this from a template. I don't understand why all of these things are happening. :/

Comment: Jquery.scrollTo is a jquery plugin.somewhere in your code you have used this scrollTo.try to find that. https://github.com/boena/jquery.scrollTo if you don't need that plugin remove it.Otherwise fix the issue with that.It may be because when you edited the  you removed the id or class of anchor tag.try checking that

Comment: I removed the plugin entirely, since it was just there because it was included in the template. The issue is still happening!

Comment: still happening??The links in the navbar are working. http://greatredspotproductions.com/portfolio.html

Comment: Huh, they definitely aren't working for me. Bizarre.

Comment: I have clicked all the links in nav bar and content is changing except the blog link.Which browser are you using??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your jquery.Please use of the latest jquery version 3.1.1,it may help you,And define them in the correct place of your code.Download the bootstrap and set it in your html page.

Comment: When I change it to version 3.1.1, the text on the index page stops showing up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tutorial/example you used had the links scroll to the section it referred to. We can see this is the case as when we click on a link the error comes from jquery.scrollTo.min.js.

There must be a function that is called every time you click the menu items. This would either be inline in your index file, or in one of the many js files you included.

One debug method would be to comment out js files included until the links correctly, this should work as when javascript on the page is turned off the links work just fine.

Good luck!